# how to get last month days from a period of datetime in python?

Tags: python

Hi I have a startDate and endDate in python, the goal here is to get the same day but previous month and if the endDate does not exist returns back last date of the month.

From this
startDate = '01-03-2022'
endDate= '31-03-2022'

to
prevStartDate ='01-02-2022'
prevEndDate = '28-02-2022'

where

```
from datetime import datetime

from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

period = endDate-startDate

prevStartDate = startDate- relativedelta(months=1)

prevEndDate = endDate+ period
```

how to do eosmonth like in excel so that i can put the if condition for prevEndDate the last month? or if there's another way to approach this?

Comment: Do you mean prevStartDate is '01-02-2022'?

Comment: yes. sorry for the typo